# "Unexpected Special in %:%" %do% foreach, yet the syntax is correct and the foreach package has been loaded

Tags: r

```
foreach(i = 1:nrow(teamAttributes))
%:% foreach(j = 1:nrow(allTeams))
%do% if (teamAttributes$team_api_id[i] == allTeams$home_team_api_id[j]) {
subjectTeamAttributes <- rbind(teamAttributes[i, ], subjectTeamAttributes)
}
```

##Error Messages

```
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%:%"
Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "%do%"
subjectTeamAttributes <- rbind(teamAttributes[i, ], subjectTeamAttributes)
Error in `[.data.frame`(teamAttributes, i, ) : object 'i' not found
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `%:%` and `%do%` operators to the end of the previous line instead of at the beginning of a new line?

Comment: That did it.Thanks. The above format is the auto indent format of RStudio.

Answer (score 3):

All pipes should be at the end of the previous line and not at the start of the second line. Please insert %do% at the end of lines 1 and 2

Answer (score 2):

Answered by Dason above. THe format was the issue. Putting it all on one line solved the issue.