# Why will this R pipe run but not this one?

Tags: r, dplyr, syntax

We began by loading the 'palmerpenguins' data set from the tidyverse package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)
```

This is the code that will run:

```
penguins %>% group_by(island) %>% drop_na() %>% summarise(mean_bill_length_mm = mean(bill_length_mm))
```

Why will this same code but with tabs and indention not run?

```
penguins %>% group_by(island) 
  %>% drop_na() 
  %>% summarise(mean_bill_length_mm = mean(bill_length_mm))
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "  %>%"

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Unexpected Special in %:%" %do% foreach, yet the syntax is correct and the foreach package has been loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618079/unexpected-special-in-do-foreach-yet-the-syntax-is-correct-and-the-fore)

Comment: The `%>%` should be the previous line ending

Comment: Here's an explanation of why `%>%` needs to go at the end of the prior line and unfortunately can't go at the start of a new line: https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-put-and-at-the-end-of-lines/1831/2?u=jonspring

Comment: Thank you so much for the citation Jon Spring! That was a very helpful read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've probably seen code from other programming languages where every line ends with a semicolon `;`. R doesn't require that (though you actually can use semicolons to indicate line endings in R).

Instead, the R interpreter is always looking for a valid line-ending when a command looks "complete", and then it assumes the command has ended, it executes it, and expects the next line to start a new command.

So in R, we can do this:

```
## this works
1 * 2 *
3
# [1] 6
```

R knows to expect more code after a `*`. You can't end a valid statement with `*`, so, even though there's a line break, R is expecting the command to continue.

But this is an error:

```
1 * 2
* 3
# Error: unexpected '*' in "  *"
```

`1 * 2` is perfectly valid. R has no reason to expect the command to continue, so `1 * 2` is run, and then R expects the next line to be a new command. But `* 3` isn't valid syntax, so there is an error.

Your pipe is just the same:

```
penguins %>% group_by(island)  
      ## this looks like a complete command!
  %>% drop_na()               
      ## this looks like a new line starting with %>%
      ## (which is an Error, because you need something before a pipe)
# Error: unexpected SPECIAL in " %>%"
```

So, when using pipes, you need to use the pipe at the end of each line to tell R that that line is going to continue.